# Why has my wifi adapter stopped working?

Tags: windows-10, wifi-configuration

I was using my laptop this morning, and the next time I turned it on it stopped working. Right now it won’t let me connect to any networks, even when I plug in a USB wireless adapter, it still won’t let my connect. I went into settings and clicked view  your network properties and it says:
“connectivity (IPv4/IPv6)        Disconnected.” Do I have to install new drivers?
I have a HP elitebook 8540p.
Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try restarting?

Comment: Yes many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

1. Check if there is a shortcut driver on your computer. If not, go to the following URL to download it.

HP Quick Launch Buttons

https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-8540p-notebook-pc/4097214

2. Then press Fn+F11 to open WIFI.
3. Connect to the wifi we can use.

Comment: Do you know what the driver is called? There are so many!

Comment: Never mind I found it!